# Non 0 value for numberOfRowsInSection causing error in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am creating an app in Xcode using swift and I am having a bit of trouble with my `tableViewController` swift file. I would normally like the bit of code dealing with rows in the table to look like this:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return myArray.count
}
```

The myArray.count is a dynamic value and at the time of running the simulator it was 2, but it kept causing a crash so I tried to see if I could amend it by simply putting in a static value of, for example, 1. This too caused a crash. In fact, the only value which didn't cause in error was 0. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

**Error info:**

> The error in the log is: "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

I also get an error in the appdelegate.swift file saying, unfortunately, thread 1: signal SIGBART.

No idea why this would be causing an error. Any ideas?

Comment: can you show `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code?

Comment: check your data sources and delegates are self to controller.

Comment: do you give right identifier for cell ? tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Comment: The reuse identifier was off by one letter -_-. Thanks guys